# Contest Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

http://hmmt.mit.edu/static/archive/february/solutions/1998/advtop.pdf

In the solution of Question 10 I'm unsure how they obtained the recurrence

$F(2)=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{A(1)}{4}$ does anyone have an explanation from first principles?

Comment: Ok I think I understand, so suppose they are two games up, they can either win in Sanfrancisco and then earthquake or no earth quake they win the series, or lose in san Francisco and there be an earth quake and still win. In addition if they lose and there is no earthquake then the probability they win is $A(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment is correct

> so suppose they are two games up, they can either win in San Francisco
>   and then earthquake or no earth quake they win the series, or lose in
>   san Francisco and there be an earth quake and still win. In addition
>   if they lose and there is no earthquake then the probability they win
>   is $A(1)$.

The probability the San Francisco Gammas win in San Francisco is $\frac12$.  Independently the probability there is an earthquake is also $\frac12$.

If either or both happen (probability $\frac34$) and the San Francisco Gammas started two games up they will win the series.

If neither happen (probability $\frac14$) and the San Francisco Gammas started two games up the then they will be one game up going to the Oakland Alphas and the conditional probability of them then winning the series is A(1).

So $F(2) = \frac34 + \frac14 A(1)$.